tmux: How do I passthrough specific escape sequences?
My terminal emulator sends \x1b[27;33;44~ when I press cmd+,. This escape sequence will be interpreted correctly by emacs due to my config. But tmux doesn't correctly pass this escape sequence to emacs. What can I do?
GPT4 suggests this workaround, but it seems limited to only 20 keys:

Open your ~/.tmux.conf file in a text editor.
Add a line to define this key sequence as a user key. Tmux supports up to 20 user-defined keys (User0 to User19). For example, if this is your first user-defined key, you might use User0:
set -s user-keys[0] "\x1b[27;33;44~"


Bind this user key to send itself when pressed. This step ensures that the keypress is forwarded correctly to the applications running inside tmux:
bind-key -n User0 send-keys "\x1b[27;33;44~"



I would prefer if I could just pass all \x1b[27;33;.*~ escape sequences.

Not sure if you ever solved this .. but there is an option in tmux to allow for passing through escape sequences, see here: https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-passthrough-escape-sequence-and-how-do-i-use-it.
I'm not an emacs user so I can't test this, but I believe you'd need to wrap your sequence. Something like: "\x1bPtmux;\x1b\x1b[27;33;44~\x1b". Remember to update your tmux.conf with the allow-passthrough option set.

@Harv But then the escape sequence would not work outside of tmux? So emacs needs to support getting both the normal version and the wrapped version?

I’m under the impression it strips off the wrapper escape sequence and passes through the rest.
